# How to store the session of a User like gmail using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

1. Login to gmail account.
2. Without logout the gmail off the system.
3. On the system and open same browser and open gmail.
4. I able to login without giving the credentials in to gmail.
5. How can I able to do like above in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

store the email in session as

```
    session["user"] = emailtext.text
```

and in every page check the session as

```
    if(session["user"]!=null)
    {
          //do something
    }
    else
    {
       response.redirect(login.aspx)
    }
```

and you can go for formauthentication to display the email

hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply.
Is the session is maintained when I Off the System ?

Comment: @ajaykumar no session will not maintain only cookie will be maintain if this is helpfull means tick the answer